# Generation of snakecase format for definitions in swagger.json in Dropwizard

Tags: json, swagger, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard framework for our project in which I am using @JsonSnakeCase annotation for converting the format from CamelCase to snake_case. But when I try to generate swagger.json by using swagger annotations, it generates the definitions in CamelCase. Is there any configuration in swagger which I need to set, to change the format of attributes from CamelCase to snake_case ?

My model class :

```
@Data
@JsonSnakeCase

public class ServiceRequest {
 @NotNull
 private Long categoryId;

 @NotNull @NotEmpty
 private String serviceName;

 @NotNull @NotEmpty
 private String serviceDesc;

private boolean isRootService;
private Long parentServiceId;

private String imageLink;
private String imageDescription;
private String videoLink;
private String serviceHelpText;
```

}

This is how the swagger.json is generated

```
"ServiceRequest": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "categoryId",
            "serviceDesc",
            "serviceName"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "categoryId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            },
            "serviceName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "serviceDesc": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "parentServiceId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            },
            "imageLink": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "imageDescription": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "videoLink": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "serviceHelpText": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "rootService": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "default": false
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ObjectMapper` with Swagger does not take this into consideration. You can specify your own mapper to be used by swagger for model conversions.

```
ObjectMapper converter = new ObjectMapper();
converter.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new ModelResolver(converter));
```

FYI `ModelConverter` is a singleton of `Swagger` core. So this might affect all the places where it is being used.